# Prove that $s(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$ is always increasing

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I want to prove that $s(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$ is always increasing.
I know from previous work that taking the derivative and proving that it is always greater than $0$ is one way to prove $s(z)$ is always increasing.

How do I go about proving that the derivative $s'(z)=\frac{e^z}{(e^z+1)^2}$ is positive?
I know from plotting it graphically that I can see it is always positive, and from observing its limits I know the derivative approaches $0$ as $z\rightarrow -\infty,$ and $\infty$ as $z\rightarrow \infty$.

Is there a more rigorous proof I can use to show that $s'(z) > 0$ for all values of $z?$

Comment: The function $e^x >0$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Can $e^z$ be negative ? Can $(e^z+1)^2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think I didn't phrased my question well, sorry about that. I know $e^z$ is always positive but I was looking for a formal proof I could use for show $e^z$ is always positive to then prove that $s'(z) > 0$ since $e^z$ is always positive. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Olek What is your definition of $\exp(x)$ ? If you take the def. $\exp(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ for $x\geq0$, then it is obvious. If you take the power series then it is also obvious for $x\geq0$ and you can conclude with $\exp(-x)=\frac1{\exp(x)}$.

Answer (score 6):

$e^z$ is increasing, $e^{-z}$ is decreasing, $e^{-z}+1$ is decreasing and positive, $\dfrac1{e^{-z}+1}$ is increasing.

---

$$z_0<z_1\implies-z_0>-z_1\implies e^{-z_0}>e^{-z_1}\implies e^{-z_0}+1>e^{-z_1}+1>0 
\\\implies\frac1{e^{-z_0}+1}<\frac1{e^{-z_1}+1}.$$

Comment: Slick, uses very little machinery 

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @Olek Just one question: How do you accept that $\exp$ is increasing but not that it is strictly positive (just asking out of curiosity) ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I know that an exp is always positive and increasing, but didn't want to just simply use that as the proof for why s(z) is always increasing. I wanted to provide some steps for myself to prove why the exp is always positive and increasing in a rigorous way. I didn't phrase the question well I think but yeah just wanted to see a formal proof to use in the context of what I was doing.

Comment: @Olek In the - in my opinion great - post by Daoust, it was never proven that $\exp$ is increasing....

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: the OP's question was unclear (what needed to be justified).